# Anti-rootkit tool for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, anti-spyware

Which anti-rootkit tool runs under Windows 7?
I tried icesword 1.22 and darkspy 1.05 but both failed to start.

Icesword gives me this error:

> Initialize failed[1]!

And Windows tells me that darkspy is not compatible with my Windows version.

Rootkit revealer from sysinternals and GMER are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GMER is the best imo, but there are others.

[GMER](http://www.gmer.net/)

[Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-anti-rootkit.aspx)

[Subware](http://www.thestubware.com/)

[Panda](http://majorgeeks.com/Panda_Anti-Rootkit_d5457.html)

[Backlight](http://www.f-secure.com/en_EMEA-Labs/security-threats/tools/blacklight/)